# combine two text files with adding some separator between?

Tags: text-processing

`cat file1 file2` will combine two text files. But if I want to add some separator between, like a line or two of `********************************`, do I have to open the first file, and add the line at its end, or open the second file and add the line at its top, and then run the `cat` command? Can it be done with just running a command?

Answer (score 22):

In `bash` and `zsh` you can do:

```
cat file1 <(echo '********************************') file2
```

or as mikeserv indicated in his comment (in any shell):

```
echo '********************************' | cat file1 - file2
```

and in Bash as David Z commented:

```
cat file1 - file2 <<< '********************************'
```

Any newlines in the files will be shown. If you don't want a newline after the "separator" (e.g. in case `file2` starts with a newline) you can use `echo -n '****'`, so suppress  the newline after the `*`.

Comment: you can do this same thing in any shell like `echo '**********************' |cat file - file2`

Comment: thanks. does cat always add a new line between files, implicitly?

Comment: @Tim - definitely `echo` always does.

Comment: @mikeserv: (1) but does `cat` also? Suppose the end of the first file doesn't have a new line character, and teh beginning of the second file doesn't has one either. (2) does `echo` add a new line at the end or both the end and beginning of its output?

Comment: @Tim - doesn't look that way here, but see for yourself - `printf 'no newline' | tee file1 >file2; printf 'no newline' | cat file1 - file2`

Comment: @Tim you can use `...<(echo -n '****')` to suppress the newline from echo. `cat` only shows one when the file has one (at the end).

Comment: @mikeserv you should make that an answer.

Comment: @evilsoup - meh. looks like someone saved me the trouble. And besides, the difference is only in implementation. With `<(cmd)` the shell substitutes the *word* w/ a literal filename argument pointing to the `/dev/fd/[num]` link describing the anonymous pipe where the input can be found. `cat` interprets the `-` argument to point to its stdin - or `/dev/fd/0`. And, because they both use `|pipes`, they really are the same thing after all.

Comment: In the last example, in bash at least, you can replace `echo '***' | cat ...` with `cat ... <<< '***'` which saves a couple of processes. (this is sometimes relevant)

Comment: @Tim: Any cat that throws in extra newlines between the files it's concatenating is borked. In Ancient Times, cat was often used to rejoin files (including binary files) that had been split into multiple pieces, eg so they could be transported on floppy disks. OTOH, (IIRC) some implementations of cat may add a newline at the end of the output file if it would otherwise not have one. That's not as bad as it sounds because garbage bytes at the end of files can often be ignored. Eg, decoders for some image formats like JPEG/JFIF and many archive formats can generally cope with appended garbage.

Comment: @DavidZ - yes the `<<< herestring` works in shells that support it, but for those that don't it can also be done with `<<\HEREDOC\n**...\nHEREDOC\n`. In both cases most shells gen a temp file, map it to a descriptor, and then delete it so the descriptor is its only handle. that can be fairly costly as well for input of any considerable length. Interestingly, `dash` does not do this - it uses pipes in the same way `bash` does with `<(cmd)`. So `cat /dev/fd/4 4<<HD\n$(get output)\nHD\n` is equivalent to the first example here but with fds you can name yourself.

Comment: How can this be adjusted to work for more than two files, e.g., all files in a directory?

Comment: @d-b Use a for loop;

Answer (score 7):

Another approach without using `cat` as found from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1653126/1742825),

```
awk 'FNR==1{print "******"}{print}' file1 file2 | sed '1d'
```

The final `sed 1d` pipe is to remove the first line which also will have the delimiter.

However the final `sed` use could very well be avoided if we use the command as suggested by [1_CR](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/21233/1-cr) in his comments.

```
awk 'FNR==1 && NR!=1 {print "******"}{print}' file1 file2
```

Comment: you can avoid the `sed` by changing `awk` pattern to `FNR == 1 && NR != 1`

Comment: Congratulations on reaching 10K!

Comment: @G-Man, thanks a lot. That is so nice of you to congragulate :)

Comment: This allows easy extension to regex of file patterns

Answer (score 4):

You can also split it into multiple commands:

```
cat file1; echo '------------'; cat file2
```

And you can pipe or redirect that using a group command or a subshell:

```shell
# GROUP COMMAND:
{ cat file1; echo '----------'; cat file2; } | other-command
#                                        ^ final semicolon is part of the syntax!

# SUBSHELL:
( cat file1; echo '----------'; cat file2 ) | other-command
```

Of course, you can write that over multiple lines instead of using semicolons, like normal. And it's easy to extend to another file with another delimiter, etc.

Answer (score 3):

With `paste`:

```
$ echo '********************************' | paste -sd$'\n' file1 - file2
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `find`'s arguments `-printf` and  `-exec`, combined with `cat` you can place text before and after a files contents.

```bash
find . -type f -name "*.txt" -printf "/n This is before! \n" -exec cat {} \; -printf "/n This is after! /n" >> output.txt
```